# How to set data into a service and the get in another page Ionic 4/5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I hope someone can help me

I want to send data from one page and then use it  in another page from a service.

This is the parent component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ShareService } from '../share.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  message:string = 'I am from home.ts';

  constructor( private shareSvc: ShareService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shareSvc.sharedMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)


  }

}
```

This is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareService {
  private message = new BehaviorSubject<any> (null) ;
  sharedMessage = this.message.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  nextMessage(message: string) {
    this.message.next(message)
  }
}
```

And Finally, this is my last component where i want to get the data from home / service

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShareService } from '../share.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagina2',
  templateUrl: './pagina2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagina2.page.scss'],
})
export class Pagina2Page implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor( private shareSvc: ShareService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.shareSvc.sharedMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)

    console.log(this.message);

  }




}
```

If is neccesary, i'll post my page2 html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>pagina2</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <h1>Message from Service and Home : {{message}}</h1>


</ion-content>
```

this is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlEJa.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 3 - Sending data to service from component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435710/ionic-3-sending-data-to-service-from-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have two issues which prevent you from seeing any of your messages

1. Your first message ("I am from home.ts") is emitted before you subscribe to an observable. This is why you don't get it
2. Your second message emitting and subscribing is done correctly. However, you **never call the `newMessage` method**. That's why you don't get this second message.

Please, take a look - I've made a small [demonstrating example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-chnwcf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) so you could see what I'm talking about.

P.S. By the way, your code could be simplified a bit using the `async` pipe and removing unnecessary transforming BehaviorSubject to a simple Observable. See the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nl3c2g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).

**Update**

> I would like something like this: 112bsimtvcd2kuxvj2ww2jkd-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/… But, only i want a communication between sibling components... Using 3 components (Home.ts, Page2.ts and Service)

Then your solution could look [as follows](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nl3c2g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Just inject your service in all the components you need and use its method for sending messages and it's message property for subscribing on upcoming messages.

Comment: I understood but, in your example you're only using one component, I apologize if I did not explain myself well. my purpose is create a set function and a get function into service
In home.ts i want to send value data using set function 
and then in my pagina2.ts get the value data of the service which would be the same value fetched from home.ts.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want. Actually, if you take a look at my first example - it's almost copy-paste of your one, And it has two components - `app.component` and `hello.component`. Would be great if you provide some minimal reproducible example [here](https://stackblitz.com/) so I could help you better

Comment: I would like something like this: https://112bsimtvcd2kuxvj2ww2jkd-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Components_Shating_Data_Via_Service.mp4?_=2

But, only i want a communication between sibling components...
Using 3 components (Home.ts, Page2.ts and Service)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. When the template loads, maybe the message hasn't fetched from the service yet. And, also, you have to call the newMessage onInit, or assign it on a click event

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>pagina2</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content *ngIf="message">
  <h1>Message from Service and Home : {{message}}</h1>
</ion-content>

 **pagina.ts**



    ngOnInit() {
    this.shareVc.sharedMessage.subscribe(message => {
      this.message = message;
    });
    this.newMessage();
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.shareVc.nextMessage('I am from page 2');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than declaring the behaviourSubject as private, you should declare it public..

```
public message = new BehaviorSubject({});
```

and then, use `message.next(value);` from anywhere in your app by importing the service..

you can subscribe to this, `message.subscribe()` or get one time value `message.getValue()` or in html use async pipe

You don't need this `sharedMessage = this.message.asObservable();`